# KDE Neon fails to boot due to gpio gpiochip2: (gpio_aaeon) errors

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, gpio

I recently built myself i new PC. In the past i used to be happy with KDE Neon on my Laptop and I wanted to use it on my PC too. When I booted from the USB-Stick everything was normal. But when I chose KDE Neon as OS this Screen came. If I chose KDE Neon with safe graphics, it worked. But I can‘t change the resolution and my second screen didn‘t work.

[image: After installation]

Here the error message:

`I 0.004256] 0.004256] common_interrupt: 0.0042561 common_interrupt: .55 No irq handler for vector 0.004256] common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector 3.55 No irg handler for vector common_interrupt: 4 0.004256] interrupt: 0.0042561 common •55 No irq handler for vector 5.55 No irg handler for vector common_ interrupt: O • 004256 ] 6 .55 No irq handler for vector common_ interrupt: 7.55 No irq handler for vector 0.0042561 common_ _interrupt: 8.55 No irq handler for vector 0.0042561 common interrupt: 9.55 No irg handler for vector 0.004256] common_interrupt: 10.55 No irg handler for vector 0.626560] ige 0000706:00.0: no suspend buffer for PTM 0.6495451 gpio gpiochip2: (gpio_aaeon): tried to insert a GPIO chip with zero lines 0.649568] gpiochip_add_data_with_key: GPIOs 0. .-1 (gpio_aaeon) failed to register, -22`

PC Specs are:

CPU: Amd Ryzen 9 5900X
Mainboard: Asus B550 F-Gaming
GPU: AMD RX 6700 XT
RAM: Corsair Vengeance Rt 32 GB 3600 mHz

Comment: please copy and paste that error message again, and format it properly.  it's an unreadable mess as it is.

Comment: BTW, you have a Radeon 6700 XT GPU.  That means you'll need to be running at least Linux kernel 5.11, a linux-firmware package from March 2021 or newer, and Mesa 21.0 (at minimum, preferably newer).   Check to see if those are available for your version of KDE Neon (possibly not, since the current user edition was based on Ubuntu 20.04, long before the 6000-series Radeon GPUs were manufactured).

Comment: If KDE Neon doesn't have those versions, try Ubuntu 21.10.  Or Debian Testing or Unstable AKA "Sid".  Debian Stable might be OK too...but I'm not sure - I think it might only have kernel 5.10, but upgrading a kernel or mesa or whatever from Testing or backports is trivially easy.  Anyway, 21.10, testing, and sid all have the required versions, and have no problem running KDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What gpio gpiochip0 kernel error means and how to solve?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665526/what-gpio-gpiochip0-kernel-error-means-and-how-to-solve)

Comment: @cas the issue is completely different.

Comment: maybe it is, maybe it isn't.  hard to tell when the error message is an unreadable mess.  even if it is, the OP is still going to need a kernel, firmware package, and mesa version that supports their GPU - i.e. they'll all need to be newer than ~ March of this year.

Comment: Hey, i‘ll try your solutions and look if it works. Else, I‘m going to format the error message. I‘m sorry that you couldn‘t read it because i thought the picture is enough. But anyways I‘m trying a new Kernel Version